# Why my function don't see other options like red/green

Tags: php

```
  $position = 1;
                        foreach($SQL->query('SELECT players.name, players.level, players.id, players_online.player_id FROM players,players_online ORDER BY players.level DESC LIMIT 8') as $i => $data)
                        {
                        echo  $position .
'  <a style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;" href="?subtopic=characters&name='.
urlencode($data['name']).
'">'.
($data['players_online.player_id'] == $data['players.id'] ? "<font color=\"green\">". htmlspecialchars($data['name'])."</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">".htmlspecialchars($data['name'])."</font>").
'</a> ( ' .
$data['level'] .
' )<br>';
                        $position = $position+1;
                        }
```

That line don't work well:

```
$data['players_online.player_id'] == $data['players.id'] ? "<font color=\"green\">". htmlspecialchars($data['name'])."</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">".htmlspecialchars($data['name'])."</font>").
```

All the time characters are "online" i mean GREEN
What is wrong?

Comment: There isn't a prize for the most code in a single statement. It would be a lot easier for us (and you) to work out what's wrong if this was a little easier to read.

Comment: This comparison returns true. What's the result of your SQL Query?

Comment: table players_online have column player_id, there we will see a ID of player who is online.

table players have columns like name,level,id 
and i want:
if player is online his name will be green but when offline his nickname will be red
soo if his id exist in players_online it will be green, but if not exist it will be red (my english i broken sr)

Comment: That line works according the $data values. So, are you sure that there is some query result where players_online.player_id is different to players.id? Because evidence says "no". Maybe your query is wrong, I mean, it isn't built right to get what you expect.

Comment: I dont think this whole query is working. I would recommend to make the players_online query right before and save result into an array. After this you can in_array check in the loop.

Comment: Character with higherlevel has player.id="26". When he logg in he exist in players_online on column player_id with number 26. So it work fine, but script i don't know maybe don't notice it and don't change colors... i don't know

Comment: can somebody change idk query or smth? i don't have idea..

Comment: Are you using mysqli ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$position = 1;
$query = 'SELECT players.name, players.level, players.id, players.id IN (SELECT players_online.player_id FROM players_online) AS online FROM players ORDER BY layers.level DESC LIMIT 8';
$result = $SQL->query($query);
foreach($result as $i => $data)
{
    echo  $position .'  <a style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;" href="?subtopic=characters&name='.urlencode($data['name']).'">'.
        ($data['online'] ? "<font color=\"green\">". htmlspecialchars($data['name'])."</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">".htmlspecialchars($data['name'])."</font>").'</a> ( ' .$data['level'] .' )<br>';
    $position = $position+1;
}
```

Even this is a rough implementation. You should try to query your player online list first. After this check in the loop. I can provide you an example if you want.

Comment: Please check about basic SQL statements and joins. Who ever told you to query like your example above should not teach you.